# PowerShell Az module: export and import offline

Tags: powershell, powershell-module, az

I need to move PowerShell Az module from one machine to another offline (both machines have the same windows (10 Pro 1809), .net, powershell (5.1), etc versions)

I can't use either Private PowerShellGet Repositories or MSI installer

I run `Save-Module -Name Az -Path 'C:\Users\kag\Documents\ps_modules' -RequiredVersion 3.7.0 -Force` on "donor" machine and it gives me 50+ dirs exported:
[image]

I copy all to "receiver" machine and running:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\kag\Documents\ps_modules\*" -Recurse | Unblock-File
Import-Module -name "C:\Users\kag\Documents\ps_modules\Az" -Verbose
```

..but getting errors for all dependencies:

[image]

Any ideas how to correctly move Az module offline?

Comment: Is `C:\Users\kag\Documents\ps_modules` one of the module paths listed when you enter `$env:PSModulePath.split(';')` ?

Comment: @Theo no, could you please advice how to add custom path to `$env:PSModulePath` ?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stefanstranger.github.io/2018/11/11/EverythingYouWantedToKnowAboutPowerShellModulePath/)

Comment: It did the tricks, please welcome to add your reply as an answer

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have posted it as answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my comments as answer:

It seems the path you saved the module in `C:\Users\kag\Documents\ps_modules` is not one of the module paths PowerShell knows of.

You can test which paths are used by PowerShell to find your modules by typing

```
$env:PSModulePath.split(';')
```

in the console.

---

Below is an excerpt from [Stefan Stranger's Blog](https://stefanstranger.github.io/2018/11/11/EverythingYouWantedToKnowAboutPowerShellModulePath/)

You can add a temporary path that is available for the current session only:

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";C:\Users\kag\Documents\ps_modules"
```

To make that permanent, you can either add the line above to your PowerShell profile, or manually add it to the registry:

```
$CurrentValue = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $CurrentValue + ";C:\Users\kag\Documents\ps_modules", "User")
```

<sup>use "User" to store this path for the current user only. Use "Machine" to have that path available for all users</sup>