# How to set up Open-XML-PowerTools

Tags: powershell, openxml-sdk, format-conversion, openxml-powertools

I'm trying to use Open-XML-PowerTools.
And I would like to execute it on powershell command line.
However, I haven't got to the point where I can actually use it,
because it seems that I could not have done the setup properly.
So could you give me some advice ?

**Things that I have done:**

I tried to follow Build Instructions on the Github page.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/tree/master

1. git clone https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-XML-SDK (master) under the directory :
   C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

   And "Visual Studio 2019" directory exists at the location below :

   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2019

   So, sibling as "WindowsPowerShel" directory.
2. git clone https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/tree/master (master) under the same directory as 1.
   i.e.  C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
3. open Open-XML-SDK.sln in the project directory "Open-XML-SDK" by Visual Studio 2019 (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.6.5).
   build the solution, then run "test all" from Test Explorer.
4. open Open-XML-PowerTools.sln in the project directory "Open-XML-PowerTools" by Visual Studio 2019 (same as above).
   build the solution, then run "test all" from Test Explorer.
5. start PowerShell ISE as administrator and make sure setting Set-ExecutionPolicy as Unrestricted.
6. from the PowerShell, put "Import-Module Open-XML-PowerTools".
   However an error arises saying,

```
 "Import-Module : モジュール ディレクトリに有効なモジュール ファイルが見つからなかったため、指定されたモジュール 'Open-Xml-PowerTools' は読み込まれませんでした。発生場所 行:1 文字:1 
    + Import-Module Open-Xml-PowerTools
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Open-Xml-PowerTools:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand"
```

where `モジュール ディレクトリに有効なモジュール ファイルが見つからなかったため、指定されたモジュール 'Open-Xml-PowerTools' は読み込まれませんでした。発生場所 行:1 文字:1` means "because valid module file cannot be found in module directory, designated module 'Open-Xml-PowerTools' were not read, location of occurrence line:1 letter:1" in Japanese.

Comment: It could be your PowerShell does not have the path `C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` listed as modules path. Have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63155809/9898643)

Comment: @Theo Thank you for posting. I checked and I confirmed that PowerShell has the path.